# Python lxml requests: Only last xpath search is working

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml

Ive reciently tried building a short cardmarket(a website to see cardgame card prices) checker,
which takes the prices **via the xpath** from the website. Now I thought everything worked fine until I checked and it seems like **only the last xpath** in the for loop is really added to the list. All the links get imported and all the links work when you check them handly via the xpath.

Now I need help to fix that bug :)

Im using **lxml, requests** to read the **html** and find elements there

```
from lxml import html
import requests

price = []
name = []
links = []
xpathPrice = '/html/body/main/div[4]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/dl/dd[6]/text()'
xpathPrice2 = '/html/body/main/div[4]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/dl/dd[5]/text()'
xpathName = '/html/body/main/div[3]/div[1]/h1/text()'

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
      page = requests.get(line)
      code = html.fromstring(page.content)
      name.append(code.xpath(xpathName))
      if code.xpath(xpathPrice) == None:
        price.append(code.xpath(xpathPrice2))
      else:
        price.append(code.xpath(xpathPrice))
      
      

string = '----- Name ------------ Preis -----\n\n'
print(name)
print(price)
for i in range(0, len(name)):
    string = string + str(*name[i]) + ' --> ' + str(*price[i]) + '\n'

print(string)
```

Content of sample.txt is a list with links like this:

- https://www.cardmarket.com/de/Digimon/Products/Singles/Special-Release-Booster-v15/Ceresmon-BT3-056-V1
- https://www.cardmarket.com/de/WeissSchwarz/Products/Singles/GURREN-LAGANN/Later-Buddy-V-2-Triple-Rare

Comment: It's not clear which elements you want to get, please add them from posted URLs

Comment: for the first url it is 0,10€ and for the second it is 20,00€

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read lines from file then you get lines with `\n` at the end - and this makes problem because it uses this `\n` to search page - and it can't find it.

Probably only last line in file is without `\n` - so only last url gives expected data.

You have to remove `\n` (and spaces, `\t`) using `.strip()`

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    # ... rest...
```

Comment: Ohhh thats it! Thank you so much for solving my this :)